# Показать кнопку купить определенной группе пользоваетелей bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Интернет магазин. есть группа пользователей - "Запрет покупки", в которой создан пользователь closeUser.
На детальной странице товара проверяю, если текущий пользователь относится к группе "Запрет покупки", то скрыть кнопку Добавить в корзину

Каким образом можно сделать проверку, содержит ли товар ограничение по правам доступа группу "Запрет покупки"??

то есть Товар1 у него в доступах стоит группа "Запрет покупки" - чтение
а у Товара2 нет в доступах группы "Запрет покупки"

потому что, если зайти под пользователем closeUser ниже приведенный код скрывает кнопку Добавить в корзину от всех товаров, а нужно только от определенных товаров
то есть логика такая: если текущий пользователь в группе "Запрет покупки" И у Товара в доступах включена группа "Запрет покупки" - чтение, то скрыть кнопку Добавить в корзину, для всех остальных показать

```
<?
                                                    if (in_array($groupID, $USER->GetUserGroupArray())) {

                                                    } else {
                                                        ?>
                                                        <div data-entity="main-button-container">
                                                            <div id="<?= $itemIds['BASKET_ACTIONS_ID'] ?>"
                                                                 style="display: <?= ($actualItem['CAN_BUY'] ? '' : 'none') ?>;">
                                                                <?php
                                                                if ($showAddBtn) {
                                                                    ?>
                                                                    <div class="product-item-detail-info-container">
                                                                        <a class="btn <?= $showButtonClassName ?> product-item-detail-buy-button"
                                                                           id="<?= $itemIds['ADD_BASKET_LINK'] ?>"
                                                                           href="javascript:void(0);">
                                                                            <span><?= $arParams['MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET'] ?></span>
                                                                        </a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <?php
                                                                }

                                                                if ($showBuyBtn) {
                                                                    ?>
                                                                    <div class="product-item-detail-info-container">
                                                                        <a class="btn <?= $buyButtonClassName ?> product-item-detail-buy-button tobasket"
                                                                           id="<?= $itemIds['BUY_LINK'] ?>"
                                                                           href="javascript:void(0);">
                                                                            <span><?= $arParams['MESS_BTN_BUY'] ?></span>
                                                                        </a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <?php
                                                                }
                                                                ?>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <?php
                                                            if ($showSubscribe) {
                                                                ?>
                                                                <div class="product-item-detail-info-container">
                                                                    <?php
                                                                    $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                                                                        'bitrix:catalog.product.subscribe',
                                                                        '',
                                                                        array(
                                                                            'CUSTOM_SITE_ID' => $arParams['CUSTOM_SITE_ID'] ?? null,
                                                                            'PRODUCT_ID' => $arResult['ID'],
                                                                            'BUTTON_ID' => $itemIds['SUBSCRIBE_LINK'],
                                                                            'BUTTON_CLASS' => 'btn btn-default product-item-detail-buy-button',
                                                                            'DEFAULT_DISPLAY' => !$actualItem['CAN_BUY'],
                                                                            'MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE' => $arParams['~MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE'],
                                                                        ),
                                                                        $component,
                                                                        array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
                                                                    );
                                                                    ?>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <?php
                                                            }
                                                            ?>
                                                            <div class="product-item-detail-info-container">
                                                                <a class="btn btn-link product-item-detail-buy-button"
                                                                   id="<?= $itemIds['NOT_AVAILABLE_MESS'] ?>"
                                                                   href="javascript:void(0)"
                                                                   rel="nofollow"
                                                                   style="display: <?= (!$actualItem['CAN_BUY'] ? '' : 'none') ?>;">
                                                                    <?= $arParams['MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE'] ?>
                                                                </a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <?
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил другим способом
создал у товара свойство, в котором можно отметить чекбокс
Затем проверяю активен ли чекбокс